# Laravel User-Subscription relationship order

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

I have 3 models in Laravel 10 which have corresponding tables.

1. User (users, `id, name, email, role` and default Laravel fields)
2. Subscription (subscriptions, `user_id, subscription_id, expires_at`)
3. SubscriptionType (subscription_types, `id, name, slug` and some usage thresholds)

A user may have 1 subscription maximum, the user may also not have a subscription.

```php
// My User model.

/**
 * Get the user's subscription.
 *
 * @return ?\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
 */
public function subscription() : ?HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Subscription::class);
}
```

```php
// My Subscription model.

/**
 * Get the user associated with the subscription.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function user() : BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

/**
 * Get the subscription's type.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function subscriptionType() : BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubscriptionType::class);
}
```

This works, but I am wondering whether this is the correct 'direction'.

I tried this to associate the User with a subscription:

```php
$user->associate($subscription);
```

But that throws an error:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::associate()

Should I invert the relationship and make it so that a User belongs to a Subscription? Both make sense for me but I have no idea which one it should be.

Comment: Your relationships are fine. You should use `$user->subscription()->save($subscription)`. See https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method. Or `$subscription->user()->associate($user)`. See https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships

Comment: `associate` and `dissociate` do not save the model. You need to add save at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *save* method to add a new model to the relationship like this:

```
$user->subscription()->save($subscription);
```